# Change to hardcoded epoch time in variable?

Tags: php, epoch

I have a variable called `$end_date` which gives me the date in epoch format like this: `1539129600`. This translates to `Wednesday 10 October 2018 00:00:00`.

The variable returns different dates, but the time is always the same `00:00:00`. Is it possible to take this variable, set the time to `23:59:59` and save it back to a new variable called `$end_date_time` containing the same date and the new time `23:59:59` in epoch format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, using [`setTimestamp`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) to convert the timestamp and then [`setTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) to set the time of day, finally getting the new timestamp with [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$end_date = 1539129600;
$end_of_day = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$end_of_day->setTimestamp($end_date);
echo $end_of_day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
$end_of_day->setTime(23,59,59);
echo $end_of_day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
echo (int)$end_of_day->format('U');
```

Output:

```
2018-10-10 00:00:00 
2018-10-10 23:59:59 
1539215999
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tiIvM)